# Bash script to output pyramid-like patternin file

Tags: bash

I have to write a script that outputs some paths to a file.
Given a number that sets the max numbers of * characters (4 for instance here), my file should be something like this in the end :

```
/my/path/*/*.log 
/my/path/*/*/*.log 
/my/path/*/*/*/*.log
/my/path/*/*/*/*/*.log
```

I've looked for pyramid patterns to draw with bash, but can't figure out my case as there is a path before the * character ...

I've tried the following :

```
for ((i=1; i<= max_stars; i++))
do
  echo -n "/my/path >> myfile.conf
  for ((j=1; j<=i; j++))
  do 
    echo -n "/*" >> myfile.conf
  done
done
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Welcome to the site. There are a number of syntax errors in the script you showed here. Please correct them and try it again. Also, you say "there is a path before the `*` character", but that should be correctly handled (if your script is fixed); please include the actual output of running your script in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was able to fix the script. See other comment for solution.

Comment: Are you looking for a way of actually _using_ those patterns later? Do you know you could use `/my/path/**/*.log` in `bash` to replace all those individual patterns if you just enable the `globstar` shell option?

Comment: Yes I need those specific patterns because the tool I’m using does not work with **. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the script, this code works as expected :

```
for ((i=1; i<=max_stars; i++))
  do
    echo -n "/my/path" >> myfile.conf
  for ((j=1; j<=i; j++))
    do
      echo -n "/*" >> myfile.conf
    done
  echo -en '\n' >> myfile.conf
done
```